# NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Class:0x007fa59b2bd598>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following One Month Rails and I get stuck when trying in my Terminal to test:
pin.user

Then the following full error appears:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Class:0x007fa59b2bd598>
from /Users/lennartsvanberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@global/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
from (irb):5
from /Users/lennartsvanberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/lennartsvanberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/lennartsvanberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /Users/lennartsvanberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/lennartsvanberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:8:in `require'
from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

My pin.rb file is:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
end
```

And My user.rb file is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many    :pins
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you said you have given `Pin.user` in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call `Pin.user` but you cannot call `user` like this. You can `Pin.new.user`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the input. It seems like OneMonthRail has some "bugs" in their lectures.

Answer (score 1):

A pin belongs to a user which means you need to call it on the `pin instance` and not on the `Pin class` itself.

For e.g `Pin.user` will throw the error as you are facing and is expected. To call it on the instance create or get pin object from the db. `Pin.first.user` or `Pin.find(1).user`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a different between `Class Methods` and `Instance Method`.

Class Method:

- can be called on the class itself which is in your case `Pin` itself like if you have constant for example, or a scope or a function that you want to apply for all instances for this class.

Instanse Method:

- can be called only on the instance and its only 1 instance like the attributes itself as `firstname` `lastname` `email` and so on... and same for relations.

So from above relations can be only called for Instances:

```
pin = Pin.new 
pin.user
# let's assume pin has created_at and updated_at attributes then you can say
pin.created_at
pin.updated_at
```

And as an example for Class Method:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  scope :last_week_create_pins, where("created_at > ?", 10.days.ago)

   def self.last_week_updated_pins
      where("updated_at > ?", 10.days.ago)
   end
end

# you can then say, both should work and call for the class itself
Pin.last_week_create_pins
Pin.last_week_updated_pins
```